# Yii2: ограничение вывода содержимого бд

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Нужно создать короткое содержимое поста блога, с кнопкой для возможного перехода на отдельную страницу с полным содержимым.
На данный момент имеется такой код:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
?>
<h1>Posts</h1>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <div>
            <div class="Artic_title"><h3><?= Html::encode("{$article->title},") ?>:<h3><p class="Artic_date"><?= $article->date_add ?></p><div>
            <p class="Artic_mess"><?= $article->message ?></p>

    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination]) ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вопрос заключается в том как обрезать текст, то вам поможет функция [substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php), можете сделать в моделе геттер и выводить короткий текст:

```
SomeModel extends ActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public function getShortMessage($length=100, $ellipses = true, $strip_html = true){
            //удаляем теги если необходимо
            if ($strip_html) {
                $str = strip_tags($str);
            }

            if(strlen($str) <= $length) return $str;

            $shortStr = trim(substr($this->message, 0 , $length - 3));

            //добавляем точки
            if ($ellipses) {
                $shortStr = trim($shortStr).'...';
            }

            return $shortStr;
    }
    ...
}
```

Далее просто вызываете данную функцию

```
echo $article->getShortMessage()
```

Если у вас много подобных блоков, советую обрабатывать текст при сохранении, и сохранять в отдельное поле таблицы.

Если вас интересует исключительно mysql запрос то можете использовать функцию [LEFT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

```
SELECT LEFT(message, 200) AS short_message FROM table(s) WHERE ...
```

Не забудьте добавить поле `short_message` в модель.